# Is there a decent JavaScript carousel?

Tags: javascript, carousel, caroufredsel

I was looking for a free JavaScript carousel. I came across carouFREDsel and it looked pretty good from the examples on their site. However, having battled with it for a couple of days now I am not convinced it works very well (if at all in some circumstances). Has anyone used a free JavaScript carousel that they have had a positive experience with?

I came across this one:
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
but the only date on the page is Sep 2006, so I guess it is very old.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that I always use Bootstrap:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap offers one of the best and easy to implement carousal.

demo : http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html

Documentation : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/